# Intellij idea plug-in settings panel stopped working on idea 2016

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ plug-in that includes a settings panel to configure certain settings specific to my plug-in. 
On Idea 14 it works fine. My plug-in panel shows on the "other Settings" section of the Idea Settings dialog. I have my settings panel class implements Configurable and also persisting the data and all works fine.
On Idea 2016 it stopped working and my plug-in settings panel do not show in the Settings dialog. What have changed in idea 2016?

Comment: How can this question be off-topic? Are you people serious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone, you need to change your plugin and have separate classes for your `Application/ProjectComponent`, `PersistentStateComponent` and `Configurable`:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150516

Comment: Thank you!, just what I needed.